# Main use cases between Open Blockchain and Ethereum

Tags: contract-design, private-blockchain, history, openblockchain

Looking at Open Blockchain's [use cases](https://github.com/openblockchain/obc-docs/blob/master/biz/usecases.md#canonical-use-cases) and it appears a lot of these can be done or are on Ethereum, examples: multi-sig contract activation, execution, atomicity of contract execution, reusable contracts, etc.

What are the main use cases of Open Blockchain (OBC), that are not supported by a combination of the Ethereum public blockchain, and private blockchains?  Or what might be more suitable to implement on OBC instead of Ethereum?

Comment: Link embedded in the question no longer exists therefore unable to answer without some context.

Comment: OBC is gone and I've added the "history" tag.

Comment: oh wow `eth` also asks questiosn! :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Open Blockchain aims at building an enterprise type, business creation oriented applications. Though both offer similar compatibility and use cases, Ethereum is way Ahead due to its scalability. So, Enterprise oriented applications can be built on OBCs instead of Ethereum as according to the convenience of users.
Thank you